# Admin user loses admin status

Tags: php

Okey, so i'm working on my site, and i have two pages that i dont want every member to see, and i have tried to add a admin check for them.
The problem now is that i can only see the 2 admin pages in my menu when i first logg in(as an admin). If i click them, it throws me back to the default page. And the menu is then loaded as a default user.

Here is my login, page arrays and page loadings:

```
$database = new DatabaseObject($host, $username, $password, $database);

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_POST['login']){
        $username = $database->clean($_POST['username']);
        $password = $database->clean($_POST['password']);

        $result = $database->query("SELECT id, admin, username, password FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
        try{
            if($database->num_rows($result) == 0){
                throw new Exception ('User does not exist!');
            }

            $user = $database->fetch($result);
            $user_type = $user['admin'];
            if(sha1($password) != $user['password']){
                throw new Exception('Invalid password!');
                echo "sha1($password)";
                echo ".$user.['password']";
            }
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
        }   
        catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

// If user is logged in, load data and select page
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    require('user.php');
    $player = new user($_SESSION['user_id'], $database);
    $default_page = 'profile';

        // Check if user is admin
        if($user_type == 1){
        $pages = array(
            'profile' => array(
                'name' => 'Profile',
                'file' => 'profile.php',
                'function' => 'profile',
            ),
            'arena' => array(
                'name' => 'Battle Arena',
                'file' => 'arena.php',
                'function' => 'arena',
            ),
            'weapon_shop' => array(
                'name' => 'Weapon Shop',
                'file' => 'weaponShop.php',
                'function' => 'weaponShop',
            ),
            'alchemy_store' => array(
                'name' => 'Alchemy Store',
                'file' => 'healingShop.php',
                'function' => 'healingShop',
            ),
            'create_monster' => array(
                'name' => 'Create Monster',
                'file' => 'monsterPages.php',
                'function' => 'createMonster',
            ),
            'create_weapon' => array(
                'name' => 'Add New Weapon',
                'file' => 'weaponPages.php',
                'function' => 'createWeapon',
            ),
        ); 
    }
        else{
            $pages = array(
            'profile' => array(
                'name' => 'Profile',
                'file' => 'profile.php',
                'function' => 'profile',
            ),
            'arena' => array(
                'name' => 'Battle Arena',
                'file' => 'arena.php',
                'function' => 'arena',
            ),
            'weapon_shop' => array(
                'name' => 'Weapon Shop',
                'file' => 'weaponShop.php',
                'function' => 'weaponShop',
            ),
            'alchemy_store' => array(
                'name' => 'Alchemy Store',
                'file' => 'healingShop.php',
                'function' => 'healingShop',
            ),
            );
        }
            if(!empty($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = strtolower(trim($_GET['page']));

        if(isset($pages[$page])) {
            require($pages[$page]['file']);
            echo "<p class='pageTitle'>" . $pages[$page]['name'] . "</p>";
            $self_link = '?page=' . $page;
            $pages[$page]['function']();
        }
        else {
            require($pages[$default_page]['file']);
            echo "<p class='pageTitle'>" . $pages[$default_page]['name'] . "</p>";
            $self_link = '?page=' . $default_page;
            $pages[$default_page]['function']();
        }
    }
    else {
        require($pages[$default_page]['file']);
        echo "<p class='pageTitle'>" . $pages[$default_page]['name'] . "</p>";
        $self_link = '?page=' . $default_page;
        $pages[$default_page]['function']();
    }

    }
```

And i use this to fill my menu with the links:

```
    <div id='menu'>
        <ul>
<?php   foreach($pages as $id => $page){
            echo "<li><a href='?page={$id}'>" . $page['name'] . "</a></li>";
        } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Any help to solve this will be much appreciated!
Thanks for your time and for reading.

Comment: What happens in `'user.php'`?

Comment: class user{
  public $id;
 public $user_type;

  public $username;
 public $name;
 
 private $database;
  
  //Methods - (functions)
  public function __construct($user_id, $database){
   $this->database = $database;
  $user_id = (int)$user_id;
  
  $user = $this->database->fetch($result);
  
  $this->id = $user['id'];
  $this->admin = $user['admin'];
(Had to cut the code alot to fit it in a comment, hope this helps..)

Comment: It seems not influent, there are only the class definition, right? Have you checked if `$database->query` returns correct result and if `$user_type` is set to 1? (Pls note: in future, add code by editing your post, don't put-it in the comments)

Comment: Yeah, the query results are correct. And the $user_type is set to 1. It works when i first login, and as soon as i click on something it's like if it get over writen. Yeah, i realised that after when i saw how messy the comment got. Sorry about that.

Comment: Also checked the value of `$_GET[page]` before `if(!empty($_GET['page']))` ?

Comment: Yeah, it holds the page data, to request the right page.

Comment: the $user_type does not stick through the "next page" i click. The value gets removed. So i logg in and i'm $user_type = 1. If i click on something $user_type seem to get reset back to 0.

Comment: But where «next page» direct?

Comment: You can see it up in my main post, there is two arrays that i use as my menu. One is supposed to be for the admin, and the other one for a regular user. How ever the admin status does not stick if i click on any of the pages after i have logged in. This making it inpossible for me to access the admin pages.

Comment: If I understand, you expected that `if(isset($pages[$page])) {require($pages[$page]['file']);` load your page. then 1) put `die('--OK--');` after `if(isset($pages[$page])){` statement to see if the condition is true; if yes, the bug must be in loaded page. Pay attention this test must be performed when you click on menu, otherwise fails. Then: 1) in the browser, go to page with correct menu and leave window open; 2) modify the script; 3) click on menu item. If you see '--OK--' the problem is 90% in loaded page, otherwise is before the `if` statement

Comment: its the same problem with the die inserted.. I logg in and can see the admin pages. If i click them i get thrown to the default page. If i click on a none admin page i get the "ok" msg.

Comment: So, or `$_SESSION['user_id']` is not set, or `$pages[$page]` is not set

Comment: They both are, i have a session and i can see that the page value is ok. If there were no session, i will get directed to the login page. And i can click to all pages that does not require admin. Everything works for a regular user.

Comment: No, if the script fails to reach the `die()` cmd, one of the previous conditions fails. You have to found where. Place a lot of `echo '1'`, `echo '2'`, `echo '3'`, etc. in your code to isolate the bug.

Comment: The script got to the die, and displayed the "ok" msg for me..

Comment: but above you write that 'ok'  are displayed only with non-admin menu! We are checking the fail WITH admin menu

Comment: Yeah, and the admin menu does not even load after i click on anything. So there must be something wrong with the $user_type not getting saved or getting overwritten.

Comment: Yes, it's possible (I asked for it 1 hour ago). But, believe me, the best way to found the bug it's to do step by step, checking every condition and isolate the line in which code fails. By this way, you know that the problem is before, and step-by-step, you'll found the stupid line!

Comment: I have to go now, i'm sorry. Let me know if you found the problem, please!

Comment: Hi, have you found the problem?

Comment: Nopp, i gave up.. I will make a 2d part of the website where there will be a admin logg in and only admin content.

Comment: I regret not being helpful

Comment: You were helpful fusion, and i am very greatful for your time and effort to try and help me. :) Infact as you can see you are the only one that even responded trying to solve the problem with me.